# pass list<string> value in test class

Tags: unit-test, list

In my class one list of string is there which is get;set; type. i want to pass the value in test class how to do this

```
public class MYController(){

   Public list<string> selectedDelList{get;set;}
   ...
   ...
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class MYController_Test{
  static void testMethod unitTest(){
    MYController obj = new MYController();
    **obj.selectedDelList = 'test';**
    //above line is showing error
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't passing a list of Strings, just a String, in your test method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `selectedDelList` as `List<String>` and trying to assign a `string` to it which will give you compilation error.

This is how you should assign a value to `List<String>`

```
obj.selectedDelList = new List<String>();
obj.selectedDelList.add('test');
```

Or you can do it during initialization as well as mentioned below

```
obj.selectedDelList = new List<String>{'test'};
```

If you have initialized the variable in your class's constructor, you can directly add the values to the list

```
obj.selectedDelList.add('test');
```